# When I run my window.onload function, I get unexpected token illegal

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Please help, when I run my `Window.onload()=dank();` function, I get the error message, unexpected token illegal.

```
<html>
<style>
</style>
<body background="background.jpg">
<canvas id="canvas" width="1300" height="630"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas"); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var H=canvas.height;
var W=canvas.width;
var x=10; 
var y=15;
var rightPressed=false;
var leftPressed=false;
var upPressed=false;
var downPressed=false;
var heroX=20;
var heroY=20;
//this is where the error is
```

Function not working correctly

```
Window.onload()=dank();
function dank(){
alert("How to play: move your hero using the arrow keys, and collect colored balls for powerups and points!
Get the highest score you can without touching a monster, which makes you    start over!
Collect the colored balls for more and better special powerups.");
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
```

This is the main game function

```
function draw(){
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var heroImage=new Image();
heroImage.onload=function(){
ctx.drawImage(heroImage , heroX, heroY);
}
heroImage.src="hero.jpg";
dope();
}
function keyDownHandler(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 39) {
rightPressed = true;
}
else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
leftPressed = true;
}
else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
downPressed = true;
}
else if(e.keyCode == 38) {
upPressed = true;
}
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 39) {
rightPressed = false;
}
else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
leftPressed = false;
}
else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
downPressed = false;
}
else if(e.keyCode == 38) {
upPressed = false;
}
}
function dope(){
if(rightPressed) {
heroX += 7;
}
else if(leftPressed) {
heroX -= 7;
}
else if(upPressed){
heroY -= 7
} 
else if(downPressed){
heroY +=7;
}
}
setInterval(draw, 10);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be `window.onload=dank;` -- no parentheses. Otherwise you call the function when you're doing the assignment, not when the `load` event occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript strings cannot span multiple lines.

Comment: no problem! As a side note, near-future versions of javascript will support multiple lines using Template Strings. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of "Window.onload()=dank();":

```
window.addEventListener('load',dank);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
Window.onload=dank();

function dank(){
    alert("How to play:");
}
```

Comment: I tried this but whenever I do this i still get the same result

Answer (score 0):

I tried to execute the not working function but just came across an issue
On using `Window.onload()=dank()`

I am encountering

`Window.onload is not a function`

So I changed it to `Window.onload=dank()` and it is working. Also as pointed out in previous answer javascript cannot span multiple lines. But you can change the alert text to this

```
alert("How to play: move your hero using the arrow keys, and collect colored balls for powerups and points!" +
"Get the highest score you can without touching a monster, which makes you    start over!" +
"Collect the colored balls for more and better special powerups.")
```

[WORKING MODEL](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/umo8k1b7/2/)